# git pull with access token, git push with username / password

Tags: linux, git, command-line-interface

I've got a problem with git push. Here are many threads regarding this issue, but none of them fit to my problem.

The company I work for, has it's own gitlab. Policy is only https, no ssh is allowed. For cloning and pulling, an access token is required. Pushing only with username/password. Don't ask me about the underlaying reason. Unfortunately I don't know it.

Error message is:

```
$ git push
fatal: unable to access 'https://<username>:<AccessToken>@<domain>/<owner>/<reponame>.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

At least I alread was able to clone a repo, but I'm failing to push the changed content respectively. Ubuntu 18.04 is running on my laptop. 
What do I need to do to solve my issue?

Comment: What's failing? Is there an error?

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to post the error message. But it's relatively unexciting. It only shows that for pushing the same credentials are used as for pulling. And that's the thing I want to change.

Comment: Can you contact your system administrator?

Comment: Sigh. They are not really responsive today. I mean, it's Friday afternoon. And another colleague just claimed that it is working with his setup. He just wrote pushing only with user/pw or 2-way factor authentication (which I personally don't want to use) when it is set in the user config. But that's all. No further help.

Comment: And that's the question. How to set it in the user config for pushing in a way that pulling still is possible using username and access token. I have no idea.

Comment: Apparently you access git with this url: `https://oauth2:YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN@gitlab.com/project_name/project_name.git` (found [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#comment-3965542554)).

Comment: Err ... Yes, I know that. I need to know how to differentiate the url. First "access" is pull with username and access token. Second "access" is push, but that has to be a different url. It needs to be build with username and password.

Comment: What do you mean by second access?

Comment: I mean push. Pushing is different from pulling

Comment: I understand they’re different. You called it second access. I’ve never heard it referred to like that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You already know that every remote stores a URL: `origin` literally *means* `https://<username>:<AccessToken>@<domain>/<owner>/<reponame>.git/`.

What you didn't know is that every remote actually stores *two* URLs.  One is used for `git fetch`, and the second one is used for `push`.  The second URL defaults to being the same as the first URL, but if you *set* it, you can set it to anything else, such as the URL without the access token.  To set the second URL, you can use `git remote set-url --push`:

```
git remote set-url --push origin <url>
```

If you're like me, you might want to know about `git config --edit` as well, which will open the configuration file (typically just `.git/config`) in the same editor you're having Git use for everything else, where you can just edit it directly.  But `git remote` is the tool designed for fiddling with the settings attached to each remote-name.

Comment: Surely if pull access is required via a PAT, then why wouldn’t push?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: I have no idea why an IT department would think this ("only access token to read, only username+password = *different* and partly cleartext access token to write") makes *sense*, but if there's a need for asymmetry between fetch and push, there are the two URLs.

Comment: Thank you! git config -edit made it all clearer to me and I was able to directly adjust the url to use the new token as you have outlined. I can now get back to work thanks to you!

Comment: It's `git config --edit` not `git config -edit`